# how to delete all redis keys using lua

Tags: lua, redis

i am trying to delete all redis keys in my redis dataset Except some IDs which are also stored in redis.

```
if matches[1] == 'del keys' then
    list = redis:smembers("grid") <-- id list
    for k,v in pairs(list) do
        keys = redis:keys('*')
        for k1,v1 in pairs(keys) do
            if v ~= v1 then
                run_bash("redis-cli KEYS *"..v1.."* | xargs redis-cli DEL")
            end
        end
    end
    return "done .."
end
```

But it doesn't work and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of keys you want to delete are much more than keys you want to keep, i.e. keys in your `SET`. You can use the following command to do the job, and it should be more efficient:

```
redis-cli smembers s | xargs -I {} redis-cli move {} 1 && redis-cli flushdb  && redis-cli swapdb 0 1
```

This command supposes that your data is stored in the 0th database, and the 1th database is empty.

**Explanation:**

1. Get all keys you want to keep
2. Move them to another empty database
3. Remove all keys in the old database
4. Swap the new database and the old database

If you insist on doing the job in Lua, just call your `run_bash` function to run the command.

**UPDATE**:

As @Itamar Haber mentioned in comments, if you are using Redis 4.0, you can use `FLUSHDB ASYNC` to remove all keys asynchronously.

Comment: Nice oneliner :) add `ASYNC` to `FLUSHDB` and you're golden (if v >= 4) (and non-cluster oc)